# MVC4 and asp.net tutorial doesnt work

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have followed this link on mvc4 and a DB and it doesnt work with me.
I dont know if I am missing something. I have vs2010, MVC4 and sql 2008 (remote DB)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

if I follow the tutorial up to running the project and test the database connection I get (I called everything video). Now if I cant follow a tutorial on asp.net website then I really fear MVC is going to be difficult to work with.

The model backing the 'videoDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Update here is the code

I just did a class and connection string. For a remote DB what do I do?

```
public class video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}


public class videoDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<video> videos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. Nobody is going to want to follow that entire tutorial to help you out.

Comment: The tutorials set up was using `LocalDB` and you are using remote DB, did you adjust configuration based on that (especially in your Web.config). Note that in the tutorial, it is using .mdf file ([SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxds9ett(v=vs.80).aspx) attached DB)

Comment: I updated code above and added this connection string. What else do I do for remote DB?

Comment: `<add  name="videoDBContext"
             connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=test1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxx"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: I dont use a mdf file for the DB

Comment: I don't understad your question, but I think you want to access a remote database. Try to look to a connection string website, for sql server: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 ... the `Data Source` property is the server which you need to have the sql server running.

Answer (score 0):

Add this your Application_Start() in de global.asax.cs

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<videoDBContext>());
```

[btw. Class names (in C#) should start with a capital.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx)

Comment: it worked when I placed identity increment 1 which solves everything as it increments automatically. so the problem was in sql server design

Comment: this doesnt work (I spoke to soon above) and I get database is in use which it isnt.

Comment: This is commonly caused if you have the database open in your Server Explorer in Visual Studio. Right click the database -> Close Connection. Then run your project again.

Comment: I am not using this because I cant lose all my data if something changes. is their an alternative?Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<videoDBContext>());  I get an error here so I cant list the table   return View(db.videos.ToList());